# creating a vector with user defined class and int In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Vector_base....no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘class MyClass’

Tags: c++, stl

I am creating a simple class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>    

using namespace std;

class MyClass {
    int p;

public:
    MyClass( int q ) { p = q; }
};
```

but when I try to create this vector

```
 vector<int, MyClass> vec1(1);
```

my code breaks and throws this exception

```
vector<int,MyClass> vec1(1);

In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Vector_base<int, MyClass>’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:386:11:   required from ‘class std::vector<int, MyClass>’
vector_class.cpp:19:26:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:84:21: error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘class MyClass’
   84 |  rebind<_Tp>::other _Tp_alloc_type;
```

Can I resolve this means can I use int type with user defined types in vector like  this `vector<int,MyClass>`

Comment: Replace it with `vector<MyClass> vec1(1);` or if you want to have a vector of pair `vector<pair<int, MyClass>>`

Comment: `vector<int,MyClass>` -> `vector<std::pair<int,MyClass>>`?

Comment: What type elements do you want in the vector? `int`, `MyClass`, something else? `vector<int,MyClass>` is "a vector of `int` that uses `MyClass` as a memory allocator", but `MyClass` is not a valid allocator (and probably wasn't meant to be one); this is what the error message is telling you.

Comment: As an aside, your code does not "throw an exception". Throwing an exception is a runtime behavior - your code fails to compile. You never get to the point of running it.

Comment: @AnoopRana how to  print p if I am using pair in vector as u shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to print p if I am using pair in vector as u shown

You can iterate through the pair elements of the vector and print the data member `p` as shown below:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
    int p;

public:
    MyClass( int q ):p(q)
    {
        
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, MyClass>> vec1{{1, MyClass(44)}, {2,MyClass(45)}, {3,MyClass(46)}};
    
    //iterate through the vector and print data member p
    for(const auto&myPair: vec1)
    {
//-----------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvv-------------->print the data member p 
        std::cout<<myPair.second.p<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/D5GTqjIJT)

Answer (score 4):

`vector` has two template parameters.

- The first is the type of elements to be stored into the vector.
- The second is an allocator, a helper class that allocates and frees memory used by the vector.

You are trying to create a vector that uses `MyClass` as the allocator. However, `MyClass` does not provide the calls that the `vector` expects, so it fails to compile.

What are you trying to accomplish?

If you want a vector containing objects of `MyClass`, then you should declare a `vector<MyClass>`.  If you want a vector that contains pairs of objects, an int and a `MyClass` then you can use `vector<pair<int, MyClass>` (as the other commenters have mentioned).

But it is not clear from your question what you really want.

Comment: can u tell how to print MyClass.p if p was public or if I had some function to print p in MyClass

Comment: If I am using pair in vector